# Laravel: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client()

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, gmail

I always get this error since today:

> Swift_TransportException
> Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection timed out)

This was still working yesterday.

I tried the solutions here in StackOverflow and I have the similar .env settings as the solutions here.

Here's my .env settings:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

My Less secure app access is turned on too.

I tried sendmail as the mailer too but it produced a different error. Tried another gmail account but still the same error.

Could it be that this a google problem?

Comment: Google is disabling [less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) you should not be using a login and password. you should switch to Xoauth2

Comment: @DaImTo I'm not sure how to switch Xoauth2 with gmail. Also, I already looked into that link already.

Comment: I suggest you go and look at Xoauth2.   Less secure apps is going to be shut down in less then a month and for some cases its already being removed as you can see now.